# Angular - Show text from input to paragraph when a button is pressed

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular and I am trying to do the following:

I want there to be an input of text and a button followed by a paragraph tag. I would like the text from the input to be displayed in the paragraph only when the button is pressed. I have done this so far:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" />
<button (click)="saveText($event)">Save</button>
<p>{{ paragraphText }}</p>
```

```
export class ServersComponent implements OnInit {
  paragraphText = '';
  constructor() {  }

  saveText(event: any) {
    this.paragraphText = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
  }
```

If I use `ngModel` that is a two-way data binding and that constantly updates the text in paragraph. However, I want it to be done only when the button `Save` is pressed.

I'll really appreciate the help.

Comment: Use two variables, one for the input and one for the paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without ngModel it can be achieved with template reference for input and value of that input when you click button.

component.html

```
<input type="text" #f [value]="text" />
<button (click)="onUpdateText(f.value)">Save</button>
<p>{{ text }}</p>
```

component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  text = '';
  
  onUpdateText(value: string): void {
    this.text = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post more than code, you need to explain the code.

Comment: You could also use `(click)="text = f.value"`, this would remove the need for the function.

Comment: Yes, but i like to keep template clean from business logic

Comment: This is really clean and simple. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 properties, one for the model and one for the pharagraph.
Like this:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="textValue" />
<button (click)="saveText()">Save</button>
<p>{{ paragraphText }}</p>
```

```js
export class ServersComponent {
  textValue = '';
  paragraphText = '';

  saveText() {
    this.paragraphText = this.textValue;
  }
}
```

You can omit the `saveText` method too and write this short logic in the `(click)` event biding.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="textValue" />
<button (click)="paragraphText = textValue">Save</button>
<p>{{ paragraphText }}</p>
```

If you decide to use a `form`, you can change the [ngModelOptions](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#properties) to update the property only on submit:

```html
<form>
  <!-- name attribute is needed -->
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    name="textValue"
    [(ngModel)]="textValue"
    [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'submit' }"
  />
  <button>Save</button>
  <p>{{ textValue }}</p>
</form>
```

With this logic you can have only one property.

Comment: This gave me some more insight as well. Thanks a lot for your help!